# Should we create [dyncall] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

I asked a question: [Is dcbFreeCallback safe when the registered callback function is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919363/is-dcbfreecallback-safe-when-the-registered-callback-function-is-running)

I think the most appropriate tag for the question is [dyncall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dyncall), which is a widely used library. Also, there were many questions to be classified under the tag https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=dyncall .

Unfortunately, I did not have enough reputation to create the tag. Is there anyone who can create the [dyncall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dyncall) tag?

Comment: [It has](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22dyncall%22+is%3Aquestion) only 4 questions

Comment: Five including mine

Comment: "widely used library" [citation needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the [dyncall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dyncall) tag for you. You can only have 5 tags per question, so I removed the [dangling-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dangling-pointer) tag.